# Delphi annotations + enumeration sets. Constant expression?

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, annotations

I have a class that I want to annotate with an enumeration set.

I defined the custom attribute class and everything. I wanted to define the enumeration set elsewhere in a resource file and just apply the annotation with this predefined enum set. But, the compiler complains that it expects a constant expression ( the enum set was defined in a const block though)

Then, if I pass in an hardcoded enum set, it does not complains.

Why doesn't this compile? And how could I define the enum sets in another resource file and use them in annotations, instead of having to hardcode them in the annotations?

```
// resources.pas 

interface

type

TMyEnum = (val1, val2, val3);

TEnumSet = set of TMyEnum;

const enumSet1 : TEnumSet = [val1, val2]; 

// Class.pas

interface

uses resources;

type 

TMyAnnotation = class(TCustomAttribute)
begin
public
constructor Create(const aSet : TEnumSet);
end;

[TMyAnnotation(enumSet1)] // Fail, Constant expression expected here!
TMyClass = class(TObject)
begin
end;

[TMyAnnotation([val1, val2])] // Compiles
TMyClass = class(TObject)
begin
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the rules of the language, a typed constant is not a [constant expression](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants), and attribute constructors must be passed [constant expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Annotating_Types_and_Type_Members).

You had declared a typed constant. Use a constant expression instead:

```
const enumSet1 = [val1, val2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug.

I needed to declare the const

```
const enumSet1 = [val1, val2];
```

instead of

```
const enumSet1 : TEnumSet = [val1, val2];
```

Why didn't it compile anyways?